# Event handler inside angular directives

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to understand a bit further how directives work, so I wrote this simple directive:

```
Avraam.directive('whoami',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        template:"<label id='avraam'>Avraam</label>",
        link:function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var avraam = $(element).find('#avraam');
            $(avraam).hide();

        }
    }
});
```

People support that the DOM manipulation should be done inside the directive, so I want to ask **how can I create an ng-click event handler inside the directive**, when the user clicks on the element the elemented will be hidded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all that is needed is to hide the element, it can be achieved via `ngClick` and `ngHide` in the template...

```
Avraam.directive('whoami',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        scope: {},
        template:"<label ng-click='hidden = true' ng-hide='hidden' id='avraam'>Avraam</label>"
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WfD9f/)

If you need a click handler to do some other work, you can use `ngClick` in the template to call a method on the scope...

```
Avraam.directive('whoami',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        template:"<label ng-click='doSomething()' id='avraam'>Avraam</label>",
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.doSomething = function () {
                // do work with $element here
                alert($element.text());
            };
        }
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kDaG3/)

And here's a variation using a click handler...

```
Avraam.directive('whoami',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        template:"<label id='avraam'>Avraam</label>",
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.on("click", function () {
                alert(element.text());
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-click is a directive, it sounds like you want to add a click handler to your own directive.  To do this you would simply add the handler to your element in the link method:

```
Avraam.directive('whoami',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        template:"<label id='avraam'>Avraam</label>",
        link:function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("click", function(){
                $(this).hide();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I want to add a click handler to your my directive

Comment: @Avraam I updated the code to hide the element on click